# jQuery / Ajax links

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a question on jQuery / Ajax, I don't know if what I want to do is ok or not, hope it is.

Anyways here's the problem:

I have multiple hidden divs in a page, that are showed on a click of a link that has a class, the reason is so that I don"t have 30+ html pages to do.

But I have a slider on the homepage that when we click on, redirects to this page, and has to execute that show commande.

Here is my logic:

```
if previousUrl='index.html#cool'{
     hide '#main';
     show '#cool';
}
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on previous URL.
On your homepage, you could have redirections to your specific page with a hashtag

```
'yourpage#div-to-show'
```

Then on that page, you can read the hashtag

```
window.location.hash; // '#div-to-show'
```

So you could achieve your stuff

```
$('.div').hide() // Assuming your divs have class="div". However you could hide divs with CSS by default.
$(window.location.hash).show()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will most likely help alot ! I'll try this in a couple of hours.
Thanks alot